# SwiftMailer Emails Getting delivered very slowly

Tags: php, performance, email, swiftmailer

Hai I am using swift Mailer in php i use the following code as suggested in documentation

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com', 25, 'tls'))
  ->setUsername('XXXXX')
  ->setPassword('xxxxx')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
  ->setFrom(['xxxxxxxx' => 'ABBE Group'])
  ->setTo(['xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx'])
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

It takes nearly 4 to 5 minutes to receive email to my mail ID, even the php mailer takes the same time, the application is hosted in windows 2012 server, and i use XAMPP to host my application, any suggestions will be really appreciated.